# How to do a pandas groupby operation on one column but keep the other in the resulting dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

My question is about groupby operation with pandas. I have the following DataFrame :

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(4), "B": ["PO", "PO", "PA", "PA"], "C": ["Est", "Est", "West", "West"]})

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   A   B     C
0  0  PO   Est
1  1  PO   Est
2  2  PA  West
3  3  PA  West
```

This is what I would like to do : I want to group by column B and do a sum on column A. But at the end, I would like column C to still be in the DataFrame. If I do :

```
In [8]: df.groupby(by="B").aggregate(pd.np.sum)
Out[8]: 
    A
B    
PA  5
PO  1
```

It does the job but column C is missing. I can also do this :

```
In [9]: df.groupby(by=["B", "C"]).aggregate(pd.np.sum)
Out[9]: 
         A
B  C      
PA West  5
PO Est   1
```

or

```
In [11]: df.groupby(by=["B", "C"], as_index=False).aggregate(pd.np.sum)
Out[11]: 
    B     C  A
0  PA  West  5
1  PO   Est  1
```

But in both cases it group by B AND C and not just B and keeps the C value. Is what I want to do irrelevant or is there a way to do it ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

try to use [DataFrameGroupBy.agg()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) method with `dict of {column -> function}`:

```
In [6]: df.groupby('B').agg({'A':'sum', 'C':'first'})
Out[6]:
       C  A
B
PA  West  5
PO   Est  1
```

From docs:

> Function to use for aggregating groups. If a function, must either
>   work when passed a DataFrame or when passed to DataFrame.apply. If
>   passed a dict, the keys must be DataFrame column names.

or something like this depending on your goals:

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": range(4), "B": ["PO", "PO", "PA", "PA"], "C": ["Est1", "Est2", "West1", "West2"]})

In [9]: df.groupby('B').agg({'A':'sum', 'C':'first'})
Out[9]:
        C  A
B
PA  West1  5
PO   Est1  1

In [10]: df['sum_A'] = df.groupby('B')['A'].transform('sum')

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   A   B      C  sum_A
0  0  PO   Est1      1
1  1  PO   Est2      1
2  2  PA  West1      5
3  3  PA  West2      5
```

Comment: This works if the `C` value is the same over all values that are being grouped. Otherwise a `merge` would do the job.

Comment: @Khris, thank you for your hint! I've added an alternative solution which uses `.transform()` method

Comment: Wonderful !! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not familiar with but maybe this question could ends in the python/pandas wiki or documentation of stackoverflow ?

Comment: @Ger, i think it's documented pretty well [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation)

Comment: @MaxU: Thank you for reminding me of the `transform` function, I have overlooked that so far and solved problems with cumbersome merging instead.

Comment: you can also use any arbitrary function instead of a magic string `sum` etc

Comment: I just merged back the grouped to the original dataframe, selected the rows with identical values in the duplicate groupby columns, then deleted columns and did some clean-up.

Comment: Does this dict method supports something like "apply('/'.join)" as a value? got a `AttributeError`

Comment: @steven, yes, for the example from the answer: `df.groupby('B').agg({'C':'/'.join})`

Comment: @MaxU Thanks a lot. Is there any resource that you can share that explains how `agg` works and pandas doesn't seem to have any doc for this.

Comment: what if I need the mean for more than one column? I tried to pass a list but it doesn't seem working.

Comment: @steven, why not to open a __new question__ with a small sample input data set and your desired data set?